# Only update column if new value is higher

Tags: sqlite

I want to add a constraint, so a column only updates its value if the new value passed in is greater than its current value. Otherwise it should silently ignore. In pseudocode:

```
CREATE TABLE t (col INTEGER CHECK (new.value > col.value) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

SQLite 3.7.4.

Comment: This should be managed with a WHERE clause in any UPDATE queries that set that column.  If you must manage it behind the database programmers' backs, you would need a trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have decided to use `MAX()`:

```
UPDATE t SET col = MAX(col, newval) [, col2 = xxx, ...]
```

Although technically it *does* overwrite the value, at least it can never be lowered.

When using a WHERE clause to enforce this constraint, other columns (e.g. `col2`) affected by the UPDATE would not be updated if the clause prohibited a match based on col's value.

I could not work out the correct syntax for a trigger to ignore the UPDATE if the constraint was violated. Regardless, I'd imagine using a trigger would incur much greater overhead than a simple MAX() call.

Comment: Although a trigger might incur greater overhead, a trigger can't be forgotten or ignored by an application or by a sleep-deprived database designer.